# Breakpoint in Up method in .NET EF database migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying something fancy in a custom .NET 6 Entity Framework database migration. To be able to step through and follow the flow of my code, I set a breakpoint in the Up method before running `dotnet ef database update`. But execution didn't stop at the breakpoint. Is there a way to run the migration in debug mode so that the breakpoint works?

The only occurrence of the word "debug" in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet is in the command line argument `--configuration Debug`. I added that to the database update command but it didn't achieve the result I'm looking for.

I do know that the Up method is being called because executing the migration gives me an error message in the PowerShell window that would be generated by a file read that occurs after the breakpoint (which is what I want to debug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Debug` configuration

```cs
dotnet ef database update --configuration Debug
```

Put into your migration code `Debugger.Launch()`:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    Debugger.Launch();
    
   ... // rest of the code
}
```

After hitting `Debugger.Launch()`, Windows will ask which debugger to use. The you will be able to debug your code.

Comment: Excellent, it worked, thanks! (Except that I forgot to add `--configuration Debug` but it worked anyway. Maybe Debug is already the default when I run locally.)  For the benefit of others reading this: The choices it gave me for debugging were a new instance of each version of Visual Studio I have installed or the solution I already had open in Visual Studio. I chose the latter. Once I chose it, it was as though there were a breakpoint immediately above `Debugger.Launch();`, and I was able to begin stepping through.