# Debugging Entity Framework Core project

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to debug Entity Framework Core. I mean not `with` EF Core but to put itself in debug mode.

I took the project from GitHub, I opened it in Visual Studio and it builds. The problem is that I didn't figure out how to use it. I saw that are there 2 console applications. I don't know what is for what. I have tried both of them, filling in Properties->Debug->Command line arguments with the same arguments I would use in Visual Studio when using EF Core. As it seems, the format/syntax expected is the one form .NET Cli, not the one from Package Manager Console.

Maybe somebody could give me an example here of what to put in command line arguments box. I am specifically interested in this moment about scaffolding.

I have tried for dotnet-ef project:

```
dbcontext scaffold "Name=ConnectionStrings:TargetProgramDatabase"
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
 --use-database-names
 --no-pluralize
 --no-build
 --context-dir Data
 --output-dir Models
 --context TargetProgram.Data
 --project "C:\Programs\TargetProgram"
```

It calls few times dotnet successfully and dotnet finally breaks with InvalidOperationException.

I have tried also the EF project, except there seems not to exist "--no-build" option. Another problem there is that it requires "--assembly" and I'm not sure what to put there. But it seems only this project out of the two implements scaffolding.

Another thing is that it calls `dotnet` early enough and does not seem to use most of that code from EF Core project. I mean I want to be able to step through  the code which interrogates the database, produces C# context and classes corresponding to database tables etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breakpoint in Up method in .NET EF database migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73922398/breakpoint-in-up-method-in-net-ef-database-migration)

Comment: Good to know but in this moment I am interested in scaffolding in which case I don't know where to put that Debugger.Launch(). Plus, I would like to work not with target project but with EF Core project so I can do scaffolding and debug the process even when the target project does not work or even can not be built.